# I am creating a live database that timestamps a process. Timestamps of duplicate entries are not going in the correct row

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, timestamp

[In this image, when the same serial number is entered, the timestamp does not go in the row of original entry when the duplicate entry is entered. I am trying to fix this. The code does delete duplicate entries as intended but isn't putting the timestamps in the correct place.

[image]

This is the current code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    ' Define the range where you want to remove duplicates (Column A in this case)
    Set KeyCells = Range("A:A")
    
    ' Check if the change occurred in the specified range
    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Target) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        On Error Resume Next
        For Each cell In KeyCells
            If Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
                If Not dict.Exists(cell.Value) Then
                    dict(cell.Value) = cell.Row ' Store the row of the original entry
                Else
                    ' Clear contents only if the current row is not the same as the original
                    If cell.Row <> dict(cell.Value) Then
                        cell.ClearContents
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next cell
        On Error GoTo 0
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
    
    ' Add timestamps in the same row
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rFound As Range
    
    ' Define the range where the serial numbers are located
    Dim serialNumberColumn As Integer
    serialNumberColumn = 1 ' Assuming serial numbers are in Column A, change if they are in a different column
    
    ' Set the range where the serial numbers exist (adjust "A1:A1000" to your actual range)
    Set KeyCells = Range("A1:A1000")
    
    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Target) Is Nothing Then
        ' Assuming serial numbers are unique and in column A
        Set rFound = Columns(serialNumberColumn).Find(What:=Target.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
            ' Set the worksheet
            Set ws = rFound.Worksheet
            ' Find the next empty cell after the last non-empty cell in the row from W to AE (Column 23 to 31)
            Dim nextEmptyColumn As Integer
            nextEmptyColumn = GetNextEmptyColumn(ws.Cells(rFound.Row, 23).Resize(, 9))
            ' If we found an empty column, we set the timestamp
            If nextEmptyColumn <> 0 Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                ws.Cells(rFound.Row, nextEmptyColumn).Value = Now
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Function GetNextEmptyColumn(rng As Range) As Integer
    Dim cell As Range
    GetNextEmptyColumn = 0
    For Each cell In rng
        If IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
            GetNextEmptyColumn = cell.Column
            Exit For
        End If
    Next cell
End Function
```

Comment: If someone entered a duplicate serial# *above* the original entry, then your approach would clear the original entry, even if it already had associated timestamps...  Can we assume that will never happen?

Comment: @TimWilliams I am assuming that the duplicate serial # will always be _below_ the original entry.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simplify:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range, c As Range, m, stamped As Boolean
    
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub 'not handling multi-cell updates...
    If Target.Column <> 1 Then Exit Sub    'column A only
    If Len(Target.Value) = 0 Then Exit Sub 'nothing to update
    
    'range you want to check (exclude empty rows below data)
    Set KeyCells = Me.Range("A1:A" & Me.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    
    'check if there's already a row above with the same serial#
    m = Application.Match(Target.Value, KeyCells, 0)
    If m < Target.Row Then Target.ClearContents 'if Target is a duplicate, clear it...
    
    For Each c In Me.Rows(m).Cells(23).Resize(1, 9).Cells
        If Len(c.Value) = 0 Then
            c.Value = Now
            stamped = True 'flag as stamped
            Exit For
        End If
    Next c
    If Not stamped Then MsgBox "No empty cell for timestamp!", vbExclamation
End Sub
```

**Note**: `Me` in a worksheet code module refers to the worksheet, so you don't need to do anything like `Set ws = rFound.Worksheet`